# Powershell remote : function with nested function

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I'm new in Powershell and I have a question about remote.

I have a script.ps1

My script can be illustrated like this :

```
function Begin{

#Step 1 : 
StartTodoSometing

#Step2 :
KeepDooingSomething

}

function StartTodoSometing{}

function KeepDoingSomething{}
```

This script have can be run on a local server or multiple remote server.

The nested function StartTodoSometing and KeepDoingSomething are public so I can't put it in the "Begin" function.

My question is, how can I run the "Begin" function on a remote computer ???

Thanks for your help !!! :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean with public, but if it's a fileshare or anything you should be able to use the following:

```
function Begin{
. .\POWERSHELLSCRIPT\LOCATION\StartTodoSometing.ps1
. .\POWERSHELLSCRIPT\LOCATION\KeepDoingSomething.ps1

#Step 1 : 
StartTodoSometing

#Step2 :
KeepDooingSomething   
}
```